# Generics in jackson for array deserialisation

Tags: java, generics, jackson

I'd like to refactor the following methods using Generics or something different I'm not able to come up with.

```
public Double[] reverseDoubles() throws IOException {
    String sarray = get.array();
    Double[] array = mapper.readValue(sarray, Double[].class);
    return ArrayUtils.reverse(array);
}

public Long[] reverseLongs() throws IOException {
    String sarray = get.array();
    Long[] array = mapper.readValue(sarray, Long[].class);
    return ArrayUtils.reverse(array);
}
```

I'm expecting to refactor those all methods into only one with the following signature:

```
public <T> T[] reverse() throws IOException {
  ...
}
```

Comment: It's not possible with the given signature. Look into *type erasure*.

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform this without accepting element's type in `reverse`. However if passing the type is acceptable for you, then you can use `Array.newInstance` to create the required array class during run-time:

```
public <T> T[] reverse(Class<T> elementType) throws IOException {
    String sarray = get.array();
    Class<?> arrayType = Array.newInstance(elementType, 0).getClass();
    T[] array = (T[]) mapper.readValue(sarray, arrayType);
    return ArrayUtils.reverse(array);
}
```

Comment: I would pass the array type instead and avoid the new instance hack.